# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v13:26

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-support-library

Everything has been working and compiling fine until I've added a TabLayout to an .xml layout. After I added it, the project just refused to compile and either all of my .xml files stopped showing anything and all of my library imports say "cannot resolve symbol ...".

I don't understand why all of my imports which had previously been compiling well now simply say:

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v13:26
>
> Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26

and none of buttons provided (e.g. "Install repository and sync project") are clickable.

Please, have a look at the gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.prett.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
}
```

I've tried "Invalidate caches/restart", but it didn't have any impact.

P.S.

`compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'`

says that

> This support library should not use a different version (25) than the compileSdkVersion (26)

Could this also be causing the issue?

Comment: regardless, use the same version for all support libs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your compile SDK version is 26, android support dependencies version should be 26.x.x

Set your gradle dependencies as follow:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
       exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
}
```

If you still get compile errors, add google maven repository to `Project Gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not exact. If your compile SDK version is 26, android support dependencies version SHOULD be 26.x.x. It is a warning not an error.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, yes, you are right. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try below dependency in gradle and rebuild project;

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

**This support library should not use a different version (25) than the compileSdkVersion (26)**

means you have to update your support library from version 25 to 26 and problem will get resolved.