# Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.2

Tags: android

While trying to upgrade Glide from 3.7.0 to 4.2.0, Android Studio complained:

> Error:Failed to resolve:
>   com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.2 Install Repository and sync project
> Open
>   File
> Show in
>   Project Structure dialog
>
> Error:Failed to resolve:
>   com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.2 Install Repository and sync project
> Open
>   File
> Show in
>   Project Structure dialog

I tried changing my `locuslabs-android-sdk/sdk/build.gradle` as follows:

from:

```
compile "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:${glide}"
```

to:

```
compile("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:${glide}") {
    exclude module: 'com.android.support:support-annotations'
}
```

But Android Studio still complained with the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v13:26](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360868/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportsupport-v1326), I obtained a different syntax for expressing the exclusion and this eliminated the problem:

```
compile("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:${glide}") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines to your **build.gradle** (app level) file.

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

After adding above lines - clean build your project and run